# How to add drawn Canvas to specific part of Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas

For example i have  a layout (or view in a layout) that covers %20 percent of height of the screen.I want to add a drawn canvas to that part. But I dont want to use it with **setContentView** because i can not do my layout operations such as textviews and edittexts etc. So how can i add that custom class to my layout. LinearLayout.addView(My custom -view extended- class) does not work.

**Note: Scale must be lowered proportionally, for example if i draw it for fullscreen, when adding the scale must be lowered to fit that covered area.**

**This Works but not desired**

```
DrawShape ds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ds = new DrawShape(this);
    setContentView(ds); // Dont want it


 }

class DrawShape extends View {

Context c;
Paint p = new Paint();

public DrawShape(Context c)
{
    super(c);
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();

    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStrokeWidth(width/40);
    p.setColor(Color.rgb(200,140,0));

    RectF r = new RectF();
    r.set(width/4,height/2-width/4,width-(width/4),height/2+width/4);


    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, width / 4, p);
    canvas.drawLine(0,0,width,height,p);
    canvas.drawLine(width,0,0,height,p);
    canvas.drawLine(0,height/2,width,height/2,p);
 }
}
```

**This does not work, no draw**

```
LinearLayout ll;
DrawShape ds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ds = new DrawShape(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLL);
    mainLL.addView(ds); // Does not work, with layout params it does not work too.


 }
```

Comment: Create a new class extending view and use onMeasure method you can  height and width and Draw according to height and width and add that class to your current layout using AddView method in LinearLayout.

Comment: I tried it, it does not draw anything on screen. Please re-read my post i wrote there that i had tried it. Other than setContentView, custom class does not draw anyhing so addView does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: what does hierarchyviewer show?

Comment: Thanks guys,adding  LinearLayout.LayoutParams  object addView, did the trick. LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                350,0);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLL);
        ll.addView(ds,lp);